# What is the best way to insert records in Akka's Actor with Slick?

Tags: postgresql, scala, akka, slick, actor

I am trying to insert records into a database with DB actor.  I have millions of record. However after operating, the database has only ten records. I know that the database connection is a state, and I think there is a problem with this condition. Here is my represents of code.

```
class DBActor extends Actor with DBConfig {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case Message(id, title) =>
      db.run(products += Product(id, title))
  }
}
```

The database is a relational database, 'products' is a TableQuery and DBConfig has a database connection and session. What is the best way to insert records with this actor under guarantee.

Comment: Remember that `db.run` is actually a Future that contains useful information about the write. You should at the very least pipe the result of the future back to this actor so you can check the write succeeded.

Answer (score 3):

Persist records using batch instead of one by one. **db.run()** method are asynchronous so it returns future immediate and execution happens later on different thread so Actor is not doing anything except a method call(db.run).You should resister callback(onFailure) on result of db.run() method so you can see if any failure happens. See example (it is not compiled code):

```
case object Insert

case object Flush

class DBActor extends Actor with DBConfig {


   implicit val dispatcher = context.dispatcher

   val bulkLimit:Int = 1000

   val flushTime:Int = 10

  var documents = List.empty[Product]

 /***
  * Start automatic flushing when actor start
  */
  context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(flushTime second, self, Flush)

 def receive:Receive={

case document: Document =>
  documents =documents :+ document
  log.info(s"DBActor received document [total count ${documents.length}]")
  if (documents.length >= bulkLimit) self ! Insert

case Insert =>
  if (documents.length > 0) {
    val batch = documents.take(bulkLimit)
    db.run(products ++= batch).onFailure { case ex: Exception => log.error("Getting error on persisting  data", ex) }
    documents = documents.drop(bulkLimit)
  }

case Flush =>
  if (documents.length > 0) self ! Insert

  context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(flushTime second, self, Flush)
}

}
```

Comment: Well, 'documents' is mutable now. Will there any race condition, if I use that kind of solution? Can we block db.run ?

Comment: No and never. Inside actor you can keep mutable variable. Don't block db.run.Please try this solution. If any issue let me know.

Comment: I said that It worked perfectly, but there is a new problem. I have about 500000 records, and I tried your solution. However, after processing, I have only 5000 records. Future does not throw any exception in the onFailure block. What can I do for this issue?

Comment: Are you killing JVM ?

Comment: For when? For example, I am also using Java's Cassandra driver. While I was using it, there was no problem about writing data. However, I have lots of problems while using Slick. Sometimes, Slick may give an error like this one. 

`Postgres: Getting error on persisting data java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task slick.backend.DatabaseComponent rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutorRunning, pool size = 20, active threads = 20, queued tasks = 5000, completed tasks = 380] `


Note: I have duplicate records in batch operation. Does It cause?

Comment: It seems your queue is 5000. Just increase queue in config file:
mydb = {
  dataSourceClass = "org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource"
  properties = {
    databaseName = "mydb"
    user = "myuser"
    password = "secret"
  }

  numThreads = 50  // increase no of threads ,

  queueSize  =1000000 // as your requirement 

}